# LaTeX ignores \setstretch or changing \baselinestretch in one paragraph

Tags: line-spacing, setspace

I have a LaTeX document that looks like this:

```
...
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
...
\begin{document}
...
some text\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
% some TIKZ image
\end{minipage}
some text

new paragraph\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
% some TIKZ image
\end{minipage}
...
\end{document}
```

The text before the "new paragraph" appears correctly spaced, however the text under "new paragraph" and some of the paragraphs following it appear with a very small space between the lines.

Any idea why it happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: if you want us to spot an error in your code, it helps if you show the code. I would guess that you closed a group before the end of the paragraph so the baseline setting went out of scope but since there is no example it is impossible to guess. (why are you putting the tikz in a minipage?)

Comment: also, don´t use `\\\` to create new lines, outside of math- and tableenvironments. Use a empty line instead.

Comment: @RunarTrollet -- the blank line, while often the best approach, also starts a new paragraph, and thus indents the first line of what follows.  since what folllows here is a `minipage`, it would be indented, and result in a report of an overfull box.

Comment: @barbarabeeton But wouldn't blank line `\noindent` avoid an underfull box?

Comment: @cfr -- yes, a `\noindent` before the `minipage` *would* avoid an underfull box, but it wouldn't really get rid of the problem that the space between the preceding text and the `minipage`s wouldn't necessarily always be the same size.  i *think* that adding a strut at the end of the preceding text, and applying a `[t]` to the `minipage` would do what's wanted, but i'm not sure enough without testing, and i don't want to assume that `\documentclass{article}` is what's being used.

Answer (score 2):

the `minipage` is treated as a single line, with the baseline through its center.
therefore, the height between the line preceding the `minipage` will almost always
be too close to the first line of the `minipage`.  this is especially apparent
when the preceding line contains no descenders.

you will need to manually add more space between the preceding line and the
`minipage`.  the exact amount will depend on the type size of the font being used.